# How can I delete an entry in the database (Oracle Sql) when I press a certain button? (Coldfusion)

Tags: javascript, html, database, coldfusion, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm currently programming a ToDoApp. When I add a task, it adds that task as an entry in the database. On the To Do List page, I loop through the database and add each entry to the table on the page. Each entry also has a button.

```
<table>
    <th>Aufgabe</th>
    <th>Deadline</th>
    <th>Erstelldatum</th>
    <th class="buttonTable">L&ouml;schen</th>
    <th class="buttonTable">Erledigt</th>
    
    <cfloop query="list">
        <cfoutput >
                <tr>
                    <td>#list.AUFGABE#</th>
                    <td>#list.DEADLINE#</th>
                    <td>#list.ERSTELLDATUM#</td>
                    <cfform>
                        <td><input class="deletebutton"  value="Submit" type="image" name="Deletebutton" src="delete.jpg"></td>
                        <td><input class="checkboxbutton"  value="Submit" type="image" name="Checkbutton" src="checkmark.jpg"></td>
                    </cfform>
                </tr>
        </cfoutput>
    </cfloop>
</table>
```

I did it with Javascript that when I press a button it deletes this entry from the page, but how do I delete the entry from the database at the same time? I can't use Coldfusion in Javascripttags can I?

```
<script>
ready();
function ready () {
    var deleteButton = document.getElementsByClassName('deletebutton');
    console.log(deleteButton);
    for(var i=0; i < deleteButton.length; i++) {
        var button = deleteButton[i];
        button.addEventListener('click', deleteRow);
    }
}

function deleteRow(event) {
    var buttonClicked = event.target;
    buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
}
```

Comment: You need to do a Ajax request to a Coldfusion CFM/CFC that does the database logic. Can I suggest http://learncfinaweek.com/ if your next question is how to do the database logic.

Comment: Another way is to make each item a form.  Clicking the button submits the form and reloads the page.

Comment: I do not completely understand. How can reloading the page help me to delete the entry in the database?

Comment: Add code to the page that you are on that deletes the selected record, then queries all the records and displays them.  You will need a bit of conditional logic to see if a record has been selected for deletion.

Comment: By the way, what is the purpose of the check button?

Comment: You press the check button when you have completed the task. All completed tasks are then displayed on another page.

Comment: `How can reloading the page help me to delete the entry in the database?`  JS code executes on the client and can't execute server side code.  If you need to perform additional server side work (like updating a database) you must submit *another* http request back to the server.  One way to do that is with a form submit, another is using an ajax request.  Obviously you'll need additional code on the server side to handle that request and perform the delete, but it all starts with a new http request. See also https://blog.adamcameron.me/2012/10/the-coldfusion-requestresponse-process.html